# Guest Software not Installed by an OSConfig Guest Policy onto an Eligible Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, guest-executable

A Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance (`$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME`) was just created within a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project `$GCP_PROJECT_ID`.  There is an OSConfig guest policy (`$GUEST_POLICY_NAME`) that is supposed to install guest software packages onto `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME`; however, when the Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) is used to `lookup` the guest policies applied to `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME`:

```sh
gcloud beta compute os-config guest-policies lookup \
$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME \
--zone=$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE

$=>

No effective guest policy found for [projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/zones/$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE/instances/$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME].
```

`$GUEST_POLICY_NAME` is **not** listed.

When the `lookup` command is used for another GCE instance (`$GCE_ANOTHER_INSTANCE`) with identical OS version, GCE metadata and GCE labels:

```sh
gcloud beta compute os-config guest-policies lookup \
$GCE_ANOTHER_INSTANCE \
--zone=$GCE_ANOTHER_ZONE

#=>

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                           SOFTWARE RECIPES                                               │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────┬───────────────┤
│                          SOURCE                           │        NAME        │ VERSION │ DESIRED_STATE │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────┼───────────────┤
│ projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/guestPolicies/. . .              │        . . .       │ . . .   │   . . .       │
│ projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/guestPolicies/$GUEST_POLICY_NAME │ $GUEST_POLICY_NAME │ 1.0     │ INSTALLED     │
│ projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/guestPolicies/. . .              │        . . .       │ . . .   │   . . .       │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────┴───────────────┘
```

`$GUEST_POLICY_NAME` **is** listed.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few reasons why `$GUEST_POLICY_NAME` isn't showing up in the response from the `lookup` command on `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME`:

- latency: it may take some time for OSConfig to propagate `$GUEST_POLICY_NAME` when `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME` was just created
- while you might have enabled project-wide GCE metadata, as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#overview), it *may* help to add:

  - `enable-guest-attributes`: `TRUE`
  - `enable-osconfig`: `TRUE`

  to `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME` with the `add-metadata` command:

  ```sh
  gcloud compute instances add-metadata \
  $GCE_INSTANCE_NAME \
  --metadata="enable-guest-attributes=true,enable-osconfig=TRUE" \ 
  --zone=$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE

  #=>

  Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/zones/$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE/instances/$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME].
  ```
- if `$GUEST_POLICY_NAME` uses a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) Bucket to store packages or executables, check to see if the GCE default service account (`$GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT`) has at least one curated role with the `storage.objects.get` permission (e.g., `storage.objectViewer`) with the GCS CLI (`gsutil`):

  ```sh
  gsutil iam get "gs://$GCS_BUCKET_NAME"

  #=>

  {
    "bindings": [
    . . .
    {
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:$GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer"
    }
    . . .
    ]
  }
  ```

  if `$GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` does **not** have a role with the `storage.objects.get` permission, you can use the `ch` command for the `iam` group to grant the `storage.objectViewer` curated role:

  ```sh
  gsutil iam ch \
  "serviceAccount:$GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT:roles/storage.objectViewer" \
  "gs://GCS_BUCKET_NAME"
  ```
- Make sure that Private Google Access is turned **on** for the subnet `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME` is running in:

  1. Easily discover which subnet `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME` is using with both the `--flatten` and `--format` flags for the `describe` command:

     ```sh
     gcloud compute instances describe $GCE_INSTANCE_NAME \
     --flatten="networkInterfaces" \
     --format="value(networkInterfaces.subnetwork)" \
     --zone=$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE

     #=>

     https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/regions/$GCE_INSTANCE_REGION/subnetworks/$GCE_INSTANCE_SUBNETWORK
     ```
  2. Find out if `$GCE_INSTANCE_SUBNETWORK` has Google Private Access turned on:

     ```sh
     gcloud compute networks subnets describe $GCE_INSTANCE_SUBNETWORK\
     --format="value(privateIpGoogleAccess)" \
     --region=$GCE_INSTANCE_REGION

     #=>

     True
     ```

     if the above is `False`, then enable Private Google Access with the update subcommand for the same `subnets` subgroup:

     ```sh
     gcloud compute networks subnets update $GCE_INSTANCE_SUBNET \
     --enable-private-ip-google-access \
     --region=$GCE_INSTANCE_REGION

     #=>

     Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/regions/$GCE_INSTANCE_REGION/subnetworks/$GCE_INSTANCE_SUBNETWORK].
     ```

And if all of the above fail, make sure that `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME` aligns with **all** of the criteria from `$GUEST_POLICY_NAME`:

```sh
gcloud beta compute os-config guest-policies describe \
$GUEST_POLICY_NAME \
--format="yaml(assignment)"

#=>

assignment:
  groupLabels:
  - labels: . . .
  instances: . . .
  instanceNamePrefixes: . . .
  osTypes:
  - osArchitecture: . . .
    osShortName: . . .
    osVersion: . . .
  zones: . . .
```